# Cannot access other computers in a private Windows network

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

I have set up a private network in my home with 4 computers as follows:

- PC1  New desktop w/ Windows 11 Home
- PC2  Laptop w/ Windows 10 Home
- PC3  Desktop w/ Windows 10 Home
- PC4  Old All-in One w/ Windows 10 Home

All 4 PCs are set as follows
Documents folder has been shared with settings for Owner 'jsosn' and with Everyone with the directory set for read write for both.
Everything is set up as a private network

Network Advanced features
Private Network - Discovery and Print sharing on
Guest/Public Discovery and Print sharing on
Public Folder sharing on
File sharing connections - 128 bit
Password protected sharing - off.
Services
Functional Discovery Provider off Automatic
Functional Discovery Resources Running Automatic
SSDP Running Automatic
UPnP Running Automatic

The settings above are used on all four PCs since they match those on PC2, the only one that is accessible to all.

All four computers show the others in the File Explorer Network
PC 1, 3, 4 cannot access each other.  A Network Credentials sign on is requested.
PC 1, 3, 4 can access PC2 without a sign on request.

To sign on with network credentials I used the cmd prompt to secure my name using the 'whoamI' command resulting in PC1name/jsosn.  I use jsosn as the name for the network credentials prompt and have tried several passwords including the windows passkey, Microsoft password and a blank field all of which fail on each of the computers when trying to access shared directories on the others.

So why does the selecting a network shared file on PC1, PC2, & PC3  from any of them require a network Credential when I have indicated that passwords are not required and what needs to change to have them actually be accessible?

EDIT 1:  I tried assigning the same ID and password for each PC on each in the Network Credentials app.  WHen trying to access a shared directory over the network, It would not accept the password to allow access.

Comment: @John PC 2 does not require a password. when accessed from the others.  Also, which password type are you referring to?  Microsoft ID, Windows Passkey, other? And how is it assigned to the Directory to be shared?

Comment: @John  I used to have a Windows password but use a 4 digit passkey now, is that what you are referring to?  Neither worked in the NEtwork Credentials prompt.  Nor did the credentials password I set up the same for PC1, 2, 3.

Comment: @john I get Error 86 password incorrect when using Net Use T: \\Computer\Directory